# What is the best way to permanently store an array with 512 floats and 1 million records to facilitate fast search?

Tags: search, database-design

> I have millions of images and for each image, I have converted them
>   into 512 numbers to represent what is in that image at a higher level
>   of abstraction than pixels.  The dataset is like table with 512 fields
>   and a million rows, filled with floats.
>
> When given a new image, I would like to be able to query through the 1 
>   million records and return the records in order of "similarity". 
>   Similarity can be defined as lowest sum of difference between the two
>   arrays of 512 elements.

**What is the best way of permanently storing this data and performing the numerical calculations so that the "image search" is fast?**

Just for background info:  the 512 elements is the intermediate output features of a convolutional neural network used in image classification.  I'm trying to return the most similar images when given a new image.

I'm pretty new to this - I hope the question makes sense.

**I can store the database in many different ways... serialized in sql database, csv file... but what I'm not sure of is what is the best format for fast search later on.**

Comment: What do you mean "sorted by similarity" ?   Similarity to what, a single reference image?

Comment: Similar to any image that the user might present - so it's not a fixed reference image.   For e.g. a user uploads an image, I would then transform it into set of 512 numbers and compare it to the 1 million in the database.

Comment: if the answer helped, please accept it.  I'd do you the same if you were answering :)

Comment: @frank I thought I already accepted your answer...  didn't I?  I'm a new stackoverfow user so LMK if I didn't do that right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be **vectorization**, possible in Python's Numpy, MATLAB, or Octave, etc.  Basically, this means you could take a different between two matrices like so:

For instance, in Python3:

```
import numpy as np
pic1 = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
pic2 = np.array([[4,3], [2,1]])
diff = pic1 - pic2
dist = diff * diff
similarity = 1/ sum(sum(dist))
print(similarity)
```

This is fast because now your operation is O(num of pictures) rather than O(n * d^2), where d is the dimension of an edge of your image

Comment: Great thanks - good idea.  So in my case, I would load the dataset of shape 512 x 1 Mn into memory and then broadcast my 512 x 1 (features of the image being searched) into the same shape, and then conduct vectorized calculations on the matrices to conduct the "search" for the images with the most similar features.  I'm going to try to store those features in sql as JSON so I can easily query a subset of the 1 million images.  Will see how it goes.

Comment: @kllc Do you know Python well enough to do this?

Comment: doesn't sound too difficult with numpy

Comment: @kllc Nope, it's not